# Migration from cstheory to Math.SE

Tags: discussion, moderators, migration

Hi,

There was [a discussion on cstheory meta](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/list-of-target-sites-in-flagging-wizard) about adding Math.SE to the list of target sites in the off-topic flagging wizard. 
When a *non-research-level theory* question is closed as off-topic, we usually suggest Math.SE as the alternative SE site where OP may repost the question<sup>1</sup>, so adding Math.SE to the wizard's list seems a reasonable idea to us, but we wanted to check that you are OK with it before making a request to SE admins. :)

[1]. We assumed that (similar to MathOverflow) Math.SE users think of TCS as a subfield of math and therefore theory questions are in the scope of Math.SE. I think most of non-research-level questions we get on cstheory are undergraduate level questions in logic, combinatorics, design and analysis of data-structures and algorithms, complexity theory, formal languages, and computability.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Totally OK with it. There have been a number of questions in those areas that are very much on topic in math.SE.

Since I'm giving opinion here, I'd be a little wary of data structures questions or "here is some code that I'm trying to find the running time of". Wary because sometimes those work as long as they're presented mathematically, but sometimes it looks like homework. But I expect that you don't get too many of those kinds of questions at cstheory.SE.

Comment: These questions that you're referring to "fall through the cracks". They've no room here no there. Maybe it's best to allow them here all the same. As to your other point, most of these questions are homework, but that's the same for the majority of questions we get here.